# How to communicate data/files between Chrome Extension & Android App?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

In this App ([Desktop Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hcilab.projects.notification)), they are sending notifications from Android Phone to their [Chrome Extension](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-desktop-notificat/giicnncicnopjohcpamieklkiacdoeni&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNECWQcOo_-frHoVP6JtXkTDvXBKrQ).

I want to do the same. How can this be achieved? I am looking for direction on what tools I need to start researching (as I am directionless to start)

I do not have a server, so do i need to use Google APp Engine? Should I be storing the notifications in Google Cloud Datastore?

Is GAE the right approach here?

(Note: Indie developer here, so preferably looking for a free solution, at least until the app gets lot more users)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a partial answer, but it's longer than a comment.

There are two APIs in Chrome for notifications:

1) The older [`chrome.pushMessaging` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pushMessaging), using "[Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cloudMessaging)".

> - Maximum payload length: 256 bytes
> - Maximum subchannels: 4
> - Maximum API requests per day: 10,000

2) **The newer** [`chrome.gcm` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm), using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessagingV2)

> GCM is completely free no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there are no quotas.
>
> (Quote from http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

I think only the second one is two-way.

As far as I can tell (**and I am not an expert in this!**), they do *not* require a separate server to handle the messages. Both your Android app and your extension should be able to send a message to a Google endpoint and it will be broadcast to intended recipients.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it is certainly helpful, so gave a +1. As I expected (was afraid off), the question has been marked too broad. I am going to do some more research before marking an answer (hopefully i can add to the answer) - thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @user1406716 have you found some new information so far? I also want to build something like that and searching tutorials, sample projects, etc. to get into.